# BigInt and indirection: is it feasible to implement BigInt with pointer-arithmetic on the pointer, for small values?

Tags: pointers, data-structures

I assume an implementation in a language that allows you to treat pointers as integers, including doing the standard arithmetic on them. If this is unrealistic due to hardware constraints, please let me know. If programming languages normally don't have such powerful pointer arithmetic, but it is feasible in practice, then I still want to know if this approach to implementing BigInt is feasible.

I don't really have any experience with low-level - as in, programming with pointers - programming, so many of my assumptions in the following might be wrong.

---

**Question:** As far as I know, implementing BigInt - arbitrary precision/size integer - might be done by a dynamic array of integers, which grows as needed. Then the data structure might be represented as a pointer to the array of integers. But, assuming that the pointer is an integer just like the ones in the array, and that one can do pointer arithmetic on that pointer, then is it feasible to represent the value of the BigInt by simply using that pointer? Then one can avoid the indirection for small values of integers.

Since the pointer could either be a real pointer to a memory address to an array of integers, you would have to have some way of knowing that you should treat it as a pointer or as an integer value. Especially since its role through the life cycle of the BigInt. Suppose you do this by setting the most significant bit to 1 if the pointer is really a pointer, 0 otherwise. As far as it being an integer is concerned, this seems simple enough: Check if is set to 1 before doing anything with it. If it is not, do whatever arithmetic on that in particular and see if it has overflown, and do the appropriate thing if it did.

But this has a problem: does the pointer use its full range to point to memory addresses? If so, then there doesn't seem to be any way of using any bit-pattern to distinguish integers from pointers: every bit-pattern is a potential memory address. It seems reasonable that pointers are represented as signed integers, though to my mind they might also be represented as unsigned integers if that makes the implementation simpler.

So, if pointers are signed; then you don't seem to be able to use pointers are integers, for this purpose. If so, is it feasible (that is: efficient compared to the alternatives) to represent the BigInt as a struct (or record, if you want) with two members; the pointer to an array and an integer that is used when the value of the BigInt is small? If the pointer to the array is null, then the integer is used. If not, use the pointer to the array and ignore the int in the struct. This makes for a more "bloated" data structure, but it might help when it comes to avoiding indirection sometimes, assuming that you don't need a pointer to this struct and can pass it around as a value.

**Another question:** Is this done in practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On 32-bit machines, the lower two bits on pointers are almost always 0 because addresses are 32-bit aligned. Similarly, on 64-bit machines, the lower three bits will be 0.

You can use this fact to use the *least*-significant bit of the pointer to tag whether it's a number or not. One simple option would be to set the LSB to 1 if it's a number and to 0 if it's a pointer. When performing arithmetic computations, you first check the LSB to see whether you have a pointer or an integer. If it's 1, you arithmetically right-shift the number over one bit to get the real integer value, then use that value in the computation. If it's 0, you simply follow the pointer to the representation.

You could conceivably use the fact that you have 2 or 3 bits of space to encode more possible representations. For example, you could have the number be either an integer, a pointer to a fixed-sized buffer, or a pointer to a variable-sized buffer, using the free pointer bits to encode which case you happen to be in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @harold Whoops, yep, that's a right shift. Never get driving directions from me. :-)

Comment: This was an enlightening answer, thank you.